# [Array].ForEach behaves differently from [List].ForEach

Tags: powershell

As of PS4 I can use the ForEach method on an array to do things like prefix all items in the array. So

```
$strings = @("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl")
$strings.ForEach({"*$_"})
```

However, with a Generic.List the ForEach method doesn't seem to work the same way. I would have thought

```
$strings = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
$strings.ForEach({"*$_"})
```

would produce the same result, but it produces nothing. So, am I missing something, and a slight change will make ForEach behave as expected? And if not, why is the behavior so different on two seemingly very similar data types?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't find that link when I searched, or for that matter in the list of similar questions provided before finalizing. So, casting to array and back to a list is the answer. Also, Microsoft, you do you. :)

Comment: Well you can use `$strings.ForEach({param($s) Write-Host "*$s" })` not much of a point tho, I was unaware of this too :P